# Activate batch file is not created inside Scripts folder of virtual environment folder

Tags: python, batch-file, virtualenv

I have tried creating virtual environment using following command in windows 7 PC:
    virtual_env vnv

It creates vnv folder with Include, Lib, Scripts, tcl sub folders. But Scripts folder doesn't have activate and deactivate batch files.

Is there any other way that I can activate virtual environment.

Comment: Does it work, though? You're not able to launch the venv?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using python version 2.7.10

Comment: You don’t specifically need to activate an environment; activation just prepends the virtual environment’s binary directory to your path, so that “python” invokes the virtual environment’s Python interpreter and you can run installed scripts without having to use their full path. However, all scripts installed in a virtual environment should be runnable without activating it, and run with the virtual environment’s Python automatically.

Comment: So technically creating a virtual environement should take care of everything right. I mean if at all I want to install certain specific version of python packages inside virtual environment, how do I do it?